# Can pandas replace method be used on a view or slice to modify the original dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to replace certain cell values in a dataframe if they are within one group(s), but not if they are the other group(s).

For example I create the following dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([['a',2,3],['b',2,3],['a',3,3]], columns = ['1st', '2nd', '3rd'])
df

   1st 2nd 3rd
0   a   2   2
1   b   2   3
2   a   3   3
```

I want to filter on the 1st column to 'a', and then replace any 2s with 9s and 3s with 7s in the 2nd column only.

```
df.loc[(df['1st']=='a')].replace({2:9, 3:7}, inplace = True)
df # same as original
```

This attempts to set a value on a copy of the slice, and not a view, so it fails to update the original dataframe. Perhaps there is some chained indexing going on here. I was hoping the view of the dataframe, which is still of type dataframe, would allow the replace method to act on the view and thus on the original.

The only thing I have found to work requires me to use one command per column-value pair I want to replace:

```
df.loc[(df['1st']=='a') & (df['2nd']==2), '2nd'] = 9
df.loc[(df['1st']=='a') & (df['2nd']==3), '2nd'] = 7
df # It worked

    1st 2nd 3rd
0   a   9   2
1   b   2   3
2   a   7   3
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Can the replace method or other methods be used on a view of a dataframe to modify the original?

I am trying to understand copies vs views and the best way to modify the original dataframe by working on filtered results.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3):

Try with `update`

```
df.update(df.loc[(df['1st']=='a')].replace({2:9, 3:7}))
df
  1st  2nd  3rd
0   a  9.0  7.0
1   b  2.0  3.0
2   a  7.0  7.0
```

If not want to change the type

```
df.loc[(df['1st']=='a')]=df.loc[(df['1st']=='a')].replace({2:9, 3:7})
df
  1st  2nd  3rd
0   a    9    7
1   b    2    3
2   a    7    7
```

Comment: Thanks YOBEN_S! That does work in this case. It is interesting that it changed the variable types to float64, whereas the other method left this as an int. Also if I were to process `replace` on the full dataframe, it doesn't change the data type.

Comment: @PhasorLaser this is knowing issue for update, you can do astype(int) for it

Comment: @PhasorLaser I have also adding the assign method for keep the dtype

Comment: I could not figure out how to utilize astype(int) for this command, but I see your second comment. Which is also helpful to have another option. Is that because astype(int) doesn't work in this case?